# Add header row in excel when string changes

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet that has a column "A" with a string path in it like this:

```
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\widget
foo\widget
foo\widget
foo\zelda
foo\zelda
foo\zelda
```

I need to add a header row before each change in the path so it should look like this:

```
Bar:
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
foo\bar
Widget:
foo\widget
foo\widget
foo\widget
Zelda:
foo\zelda
foo\zelda
foo\zelda
```

I am not sure where to even start with this as I am not a vba expert.  Is this something that is possible in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (assuming your data is in Column A):

```
Sub insertHeaderRow()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow    As Long, i As Long
Dim cel        As Range
Dim myTest As String

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    Set cel = Cells(i, 1)
    mytext = Mid(cel, InStrRev(cel, "\") + 1, 256) & ":"
    On Error Resume Next
    If cel.Value <> cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value Or cel.Row = 1 Then
        cel.EntireRow.Insert
        cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value = mytext
        colorHeaderRow cel.Offset(-1, 0)
        ' Double header row height
        cel.Offset(-1, 0).RowHeight = cel.Offset(-1, 0).RowHeight * 2
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub colorHeaderRow(ByVal cel As Range)
With cel.EntireRow.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With cel.EntireRow.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Note: If someone has any idea how to avoid using the `On Error Resume Next` (without making the code much longer), I'd appreciate it. I only used it because at row 1, the `cel.offset(-1,0).Value` throws an (expected) error and doesn't look at the rest of the statement. I used the `Resume Next` so it'll ignore that, and see the `cel.Row =  1` and add the final row.  I've just had it drilled in to my head to avoid error handling like this...but the code *shouldn't* throw any other errors.

Comment: This looks really promising but I am getting "Unable to get the Search property of the worksheet function class"  Is this something due to my data?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara - It should work. I just ran it. ...but then got the same error after a few times of testing it. Let me re-check this.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara - I updated the code, totally removing the use of `Search` which I also thinks makes it a little easier to understand. Let me know if it throws any more errors or issues.

Comment: This is perfect, is there a chance you can show me how to add in to make the header rows black, with white font and double the row height?  This would just be for the header rows.  Although this does work perfectly well.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara - Yeah, no problemo! Check my edit. I added a second `Sub` to keep it easier to follow (IMO).